# How to use xml from an android library

Tags: android

I was wondering if its possible to use a xml file from an android library, in the same way as you can use a Custom View.

For example, lets say you have a CustomView that extends LinearLayout, you can easy use this class in your xml project with . But if you have a customview.xml inside your android library and want to use it in your project, can you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. This is why you specify a unique package name qualifier for every application. You can use any library resource by providing it's full name qualifier.

Comment: so you make reference to the xml like you do with a java class?

Comment: If you are using those resources in Java you access them  by giving a reference for example com.library.R.layout.filename.  Otherwise in layouts files you can directly reference to xml files by their name. Classes in xml files must be reference with full name qualifiers again.